# Cygwin grep and -f switch

Tags: cygwin, grep

I've created a text file (in Windows) with the text patterns I wish to search for. 
Using the -f switch, grep only searches for the last pattern in the list. If there is a blank line, grep finds nothing.

grep -a -A 4 -f Grep.txt my.file

Any suggestions to get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check to be sure each line in your pattern file ends with only a `\n` character Unix-style, not a Windows-style `\r\n` combination.  To the Cygwin `grep`, a `\r` is an ordinary character that it would try to match.

You can delete the `\r` characters with `tr`:

```
tr -d "\r" < infile > outfile
```

Comment: That was it. Another option is to use NotePad++ to save in Unix text format.